# How to trigger a click of that 'link' on click of anywhere in that row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I have a dynamically created table, with row class as "rowclass" and ids such as 1,2,3,4 etc. There is a link inside that row.
I want to trigger that link i.e `a` on click of anywhere in that row. This is the HTML.

```
<tr id="40" data-id="40" data-parent="" class="rowclass act-tr-collapsed act-tr-level-0" data-level="0">
 <td id="235" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:17px;width:40%;">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="act-more act-collapsed"><span class="i">+ </span></a>Nametobeappended<span id="s40" class="icon icon-info"
  </span>
 </td>
 <td id="236">
 <div style="height: 20px;position: relative;">
 <div id="d236" style="height: 20px;float:left;color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial Black; width:50%;background-color: #d00000;">
  <div style="padding-left:5px;z-index: 99;position: absolute;">50</div>
   <div style="float:right; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(102,197,232);width:0%;position: absolute; top:0; left:50%;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td id="237">
  <div style="height: 20px;position: relative;">
   <div id="d237" style="height: 20px;float:left;color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial Black; width:50%;background-color: #d00000;">
    <div style="padding-left:5px;z-index: 99;position: absolute;">50</div>
    <div style="float:right; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(102,197,232);width:0%;position: absolute; top:0; left:50%;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </td>
 <td id="238">
 <div style="height: 20px;position: relative;">
  <div id="d238" style="height: 20px;float:left;color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial Black; width:50%;background-color: #d00000;">
   <div style="padding-left:5px;z-index: 99;position: absolute;">50</div>
    <div style="float:right; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(102,197,232);width:0%;position: absolute; top:0; left:50%;"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is the JQuery I've written which doesn't work.

```
 $('.rowclass').on("click", function(){

   idss = $(this).children().attr('id'); //td id
   $("#"+idss).find('a').trigger('click'); //want to click <a> of that particular row
 });
 console.log("id: "+idss)// says idss undefined
 $("#"+idss).find('a').click(); //doesn't work
```

Comment: What are the click events firing? It looks like you are trying to find anchor tags in each cell too?

Comment: @Simon Yeah there is an anchor tag `<a>` in only the first `<td>` of that `<tr>` as given in the html. Want to trigger that if I click anywhere on that particular row. I am writing the lines of code given above after the table has been completely loaded.

Comment: If none of the solutions offered below suits your purpose, let me know and I will have a look at it

Comment: @Simon Thanks Simon! I've posted an answer as to what worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger that particular row's  anchor tag onclick of that row, this is what worked:

```
$(document).on('click', '.rowclass', function() {
    $(this).children().find('a span').trigger('click');
    //go to td then find <a> <span> to trigger click
```

});

This may not be the best of solutions. I'm new to coding, so if there's a better way I would be happy to know about it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you created the rows dynamically, you need to select them this way:

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/Hulothe/1u8scath/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'tr.rowclass', function() {
        alert('o');
        $(this).children().find('a').trigger('click'); //want to click <a> of that particular row
    });

    // And you need to handle a click event on the `<a>` if you want to trigger a click on it, like this:

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('Clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: I think i wasn't clear. On click of that particular row, i want to trigger a click on `<a>`

Comment: @AyushiZile Sorry I should have developed more my answer. I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks @Hulothe for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To do this use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.rowclass', function(e) {
    // e.target is the element you clicked on
    // .closest('tr') finds the closest parent that is an 'tr' element
    // .find('a') finds the child that is an 'a' element
    // .trigger('click') triggers a click on the found element

    $(e.target).closest('tr').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

I think the problem is that the table is loaded after the event is bound to the element. $(document).on('click', 'element', function); makes sure the event is always bound, even before html is loaded.

Or that using .children returns multiple elements and so can not give a id.

Comment: I did not understand what e is actually? Also, the table is loaded first, then i type in the js written above. Is that where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this: 



 $(document).on('click', '.rowclass', function() {
        $(this).find('a').trigger('click');
 });
```

LE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(document).on('click', '.rowclass', function(e) { 
      var link = $(this).find("a");
      if (e.target === link[0]) return false; 
      link.trigger('click');
      return false;
  });
})
```

if (e.target === link[0]) - Here we check if the clicked element is the a tag itself. If that's so, we'll let the default behaviour happen. 
If not, we trigger the click on a tag

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Vladut This doesn't work as it gives the following error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". If I `console.log` anything inside the loop, it enters an indefinite loop of some sort

Comment: Yesh, sorry for that. It didn't crossed my mind that triggering a click event on a child it will also be considered as click on parent. That's what the error says. 
This code should work well:  
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(document).on('click', '.rowclass', function(e) { 
      var link = $(this).find("a");
      if (e.target === link[0]) return false;
      link.trigger('click');
      return false;
  });
})

Comment: Thanks @Vladut for the explanation! Helped a lot!